# Apply constraint to class, adhere to interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface, adapter

I have the requirement to be able to perform many conversions of external models to my own internal models.

I have decided to apply the Adapter pattern, but I want to make it as generic as possible. So effectively, I want it to be handle both "single" POCO's, but if i need to pass/adapt a collection then this also must work eg:

```
IEnumerable<IAdaptee> OR IList<TAdaptee>
```

and return my own adapted object(s):

```
IEnumerable<IAdapted> OR IList<TAdapted>
```

I want to do something like the following:

```
public interface IGenericAdapter
{
    TAdapted Adapt<TAdapted,TAdaptee>(TAdaptee adaptee);
}
```

Where I am coming unstuck is when I build my "Adapter" class, and then implement the above interface, I am getting constraint mismatch errors. This of course, makes sense, because If i am applying constraints to the classes which implement the interface, and the interface doesn't have them, then of course errors occur.

So:

```
public class AToBAdapter
{
public TAdapted Adapt<TAdapted,TAdaptee>(TAdaptee adaptee)
where TAdapted: IList<FooAdapted>
where TAdaptee: IList<FooAdaptee>
{
// I want my constraints to be active here, as I need to perform specific operations here
}
}
```

The above works fine in and of itself, which is fine. But I want to hide all this behind a generic interface that I can use whenever it suits.

Of course, Once i add this it fails due to no constraints on the interface, yet constraints on the implementing class.

```
public class AToBAdapter:IAdapterGeneric
```

What's the magic bullet here which will enable me to build a truly generic Adapter - I'm guessing certain constraints on the interface? casting? but need assistance on the best course of action.

Thanks,
Chud

Comment: what is the purpose and benefits of use IGenericAdapter ?

Comment: I will have many adapters, coming from many different sources. So i want to simplify my ability to homogenise my multi source data, into a single source (my model) with a singular adapter if possible

Comment: could you explain " ability to homogenise my multi source data, into a single source (my model) with a singular adapter". i dont understand your problem

Comment: Ok. Let's use comething like a hotel comparison site (it's not what I'm doing but an example) Let's say i want to pull data from tripadvisor,agoda,booking,hotelscombined. Each of these have their own "Models" in place fo what they name a hotel. Ex - HotelName, Name,PropertyName etc. I want to to get all this data and adapt it into my own. EX IList<MyHotelData> = Adapter.Adapt<MyAdaptedData,TripAdvisorModel> and IList<MyHotelData> = Adapter.Adapt<MyAdaptedData,AgodaModel> and effectively "Adapt" to MY model.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to your external models, you could use an interface as a marker:

```
public interface IAdaptee { }
public interface IAdapted { }
```

And use those interfaces as your adapter interface constraints:

```
public interface IGenericAdapter<out TAdapted, in TAdaptee>
    where TAdaptee : IAdaptee
    where TAdapted : IAdapted
{
    TAdapted Adapt(TAdaptee adaptee);
}
```

You could pass this adapter into a helper method for adapting multiple objects (assuming the adapt logic stays the same for multiple):

```
public IEnumerable<TAdapted> AdaptMultiple<TAdapted, TAdaptee>
    (IEnumerable<TAdaptee> adaptees, IGenericAdapter<TAdapted, TAdaptee> adapter)
    where TAdaptee : IAdaptee
    where TAdapted : IAdapted
{
    return adaptees.Select(adapter.Adapt);
}
```

For example, we can construct the following concrete classes:

```
public class ConcreteAdaptee : IAdaptee { }

public class ConcreteAdapted : IAdapted { }

public class ConcreteAdapter : IGenericAdapter<ConcreteAdapted, ConcreteAdaptee>
{
    public ConcreteAdapted Adapt(ConcreteAdaptee adaptee)
    {
        // Adapt Logic

        return new ConcreteAdapted();
    }
}
```

And adapt them as such:

```
IGenericAdapter<ConcreteAdapted, ConcreteAdaptee> adapter = new ConcreteAdapter();

var adaptee = new ConcreteAdaptee();
var adapted = adapter.Adapt(adaptee);

var adaptees = new List<ConcreteAdaptee>();
var adapteds = AdaptMultiple(adaptees, adapter);
```

Comment: Hi Kyle, This is close to the mark. I have to go out shortly so I can't fully test/investigate this. My question to you is .... what about casting inside the adapt method. If we are using a specific ConcreteAdapter, then the concrete classes themselves know what is going in -> going out ... so public TAdapted Adapt<TAdapted,TAdaptee>(TAdaptee adaptee) { IList<External> external = (IList<External)adaptee; //perform full adapt; return internal model;?? }

Comment: I think you would want to create an adapter specific to each unique adaptee/adapted pair you have, so that you wouldn't have to typecheck inside the adapter. If you need a way to find the correct adapter, you could use dependency injection to inject an adapter based on the input object's type and the concrete object you'd like to adapt to.

Answer (score 0):

consider the following example :

```
interface IDog
{
    void Bark();
}

interface ICat
{
    void Meow();
}
class SomeDog : IDog
{
    public void Bark()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(@"bark bark");
    }
}

class SomeCat : ICat
{
    public void Meow()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(@"meow meow");
    }
}

class CatToDogAdapter : IDog
{
    private ICat cat;
    public CatToDogAdapter(ICat cat)
    {
        this.cat = cat;
    }

    public void Bark()
    {
        cat.Meow();
    }
}

new Dog().Bark(); // bark bark
new CatToDogAdapter().Bark();// meow meow
```

this is how adapter works.

Let say you have a model MyAdaptedData and you recive data containing HotelName, Name,PropertyName  from agoda , booking and tripadviser
for each booking model you need to write adapter

```
AgodaAdapter : MyAdaptedData{
    public AgodaAdapter(AgodaModel agodaModel){
        ....
    }
    public stirng HotelName{
        get{
            return agodaModel.HotelNamebyAgoda;
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

Same for booking and tripadvisor.
Adapter pattern helps you to retrieve necessary data from external models.

Then you need to create specific adapter depending on the adaptee type. Use Factory method pattern

```
MyAdaptedData AdaptersFactory(object adaptee){

    if(adaptee is AgodaModel)
        return new AgodaAdapter(adaptee);
    ....
    if(adaptee is XBookingModel)
        return new XBookingAdapter(adaptee);
}
```